# Reproducir música al presionar varias teclas

Tags: c#

tengo una duda sobre C#, estoy haciendo un juego en Unity y necesito que al escribir una palabra, por ejemplo aloha, en cualquier momento, se reproduzca una musica, por ejemplo el archivo .mp4 "saludo"... He intentado con el código que inserto pero Unity se crashea, por favor si alguien pudiera ayudarme a solucionar este probema.
Gracias de antemano.

```
void Update()
{
    var palabra = "";
    while(palabra != "aloha")
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.a))
        {
            palabra += "a";
        }

        if(palabra == "a" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.l))
        {
            palabra += "l";
        }

        if(palabra == "al" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.o))
        {
            palabra += "o";
        }

        if(palabra == "alo" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.h))
        {
            palabra += "h";
        }

        if(palabra == "aloh" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.a))
        {
            palabra += "a";
        }
    }

    if(palabra == "aloha")
    {
        fuenteAudio.clip = saludo;
        fuenteAudio.Play();
        palabra = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Se crashea... quiere decir que tira un error y deja de funcionar no? Entonces, que error tira?

Comment: Se detiene el programa y no puedo hacer nada a menos que fuerce el cierre, por lo tanto no salta ningún error

Comment: Se para completamente... No puedo mover ni el cursor

Comment: Entonces no crashea... simplemente esta esperando algo que no sucede. Ese while suena mal... probaste hacer un debug y ver donde esta parado cuando pasa eso?

Comment: No, no lo probé... Pero me suena raro que espere a ver qué sucede, ya que en un momento lo deje más de media hora y no reaccionó... Probaré a hacer un debug y a ver que es lo que pasa... Lo del while pensé que quizá era un bucle infinito y por eso mi ordenador no podía con el código pero lo he revisado varias veces y no lo es
Gracias de todas formas

Answer (score 0):

El metodo Update() de unity es un loop, la situcion que presentas es que esta llamando un while dentro del mismo que se convierte en infinito, por lo tanto unity se crashea pues se queda parado en el mismo frame para siempre y no logra avanzar, la logica de tu codigo deberia sera algo similar a:

```
private string palabra;

    void Update()
    {
        if(palabra == "aloha")
        {
            fuenteAudio.clip = saludo;
            fuenteAudio.Play();
            palabra = "";
            return;
        }
        
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.a))
        {
            palabra += "a";
        }

        if(palabra == "a" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.l))
        {
            palabra += "l";
        }

        if(palabra == "al" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.o))
        {
            palabra += "o";
        }

        if(palabra == "alo" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.h))
        {
            palabra += "h";
        }

        if(palabra == "aloh" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.a))
        {
            palabra += "a";
        }
    }
```